# Using BN-880 Magnetometer with Raspberry Pi via i2C Ports

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to use the SDA/SCL pins from the BN 880 for a compass readout, while simultaneously using serial ports to read GPS location data. GPS readouts are working via cgps, but I can't get access to the compass readout.

Can anybody direct me to documentation that explains how to access the compass readout from the terminal or a Python script?

There are tutorials for using the 5883 magnetometer, or for using SMBus. SMBus makes assumptions about which buses data will store the data, and I don't know where to find documentation that explains this code.

For context: I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspian 11, and when I run i2cdetect with the magnetometer attached, the active bus is 1e. The BN-880 pins are attached to the Raspberry Pi pins as described:

BN880-RPi pin map:
i2c Pins:
1-3
6-5
Serial pins:
3-10
4-8
Power/Ground
5-4
2-6

[Raspberry Pi Pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roz0q.png)
[BN-880 Pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NOc6.png)

Documentation Referenced:
5883 Tutorial: https://www.robotwars.nz/robots/display_doc_Final.cgi?sesid=dntbot_598453b2Sd7sOeytI&docno=50000462&crc=45365019

SMBus tutorial: https://www.electronicwings.com/raspberry-pi/python-based-i2c-functions-for-raspberry-pi

Tried SMBus code and received no readout.